# How to set max-old-space-size so it is honoured in NativeScript's VS Code extension running on OS X?

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I've tried:

- Executing `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"` in VS Code's bash prompt
- Executing `export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"` in a system bash prompt
- Adding it to my user's `.bashrc` file and rebooting
- Installing and running [increase-memory-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit) against the project

Nothing seems to work; debugging using VS Code on Mac seems impossible if the project goes above a certain size. I always end up with `Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed`. It works running from bash, but not running from VS Code.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, you can boiled it down to. Get-ChildItem -Path Env:NODE_OPTIONS in powershell returns NODE_OPTIONS --max_old_space_size=8192 in vscode it returns "Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'NODE_OPTIONS' because it does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get this working and I thought I'd record it here for the benefit of others.

I had to patch [the plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension) with a hack, which can certainly be made more graceful (which I will attempt to achieve and submit a PR).

In [nativeScriptCli.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension/blob/master/src/project/nativeScriptCli.ts), I modified the following methods to add the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to each spawn of `Node`:

```
public executeSync(args: string[], cwd: string): string {
    args.unshift('--analyticsClient', 'VSCode');
    const command: string = `${this._path} ${args.join(' ')}`;
    let env = process.env;
    env["NODE_OPTIONS"] = "--max-old-space-size=4096";

    this._logger.log(`[NativeScriptCli] execute: ${command}`);

    return execSync(command, { encoding: 'utf8', cwd, shell: this._shellPath, env: env }).toString().trim();
}

public execute(args: string[], cwd: string): ChildProcess {
    args.unshift('--analyticsClient', 'VSCode');
    const command: string = `${this._path} ${args.join(' ')}`;
    this._logger.log(`[NativeScriptCli] execute: ${command}`);
    let env = process.env;
    env["NODE_OPTIONS"] = "--max-old-space-size=4096";
    const options = { cwd, shell: this._shellPath, env: env };
    const child: ChildProcess = spawn(this._path, args, options);

    child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

    return child;
}
```

After installing this hacked version on my Mac, the app now successfully builds in `VS Code`.